# Toggle TWO Panels with ONLY ONE VISIBLE Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have two sliding panels.  I need ONLY ONE panel open at a time.  Right now they can both open.  My project link is: [link text](http://www.ubspack.com)

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel_quote").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("closeQ"); return false;
});
    });



    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
    $("#panel_login").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("closeL"); return false;
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the link you provided but I couldn't see the buttons.

Anyway. What you probably want is to show only either `"#panel_quote"` or `"#panel_login"`. In that case I would recommend using `hide()` onload on one of them and then in one button toggle both like this:

```
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel_login").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#panel_quote").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Or if you really want to use both buttons, just add the other toggle to each button handler. And again, you can use the `hide()` onload. It is safer to proceed this way rather than giving initial css values to hide the panel because of users with javascript turned off.

Comment: The buttons were on top of the page:  FAST QUOTE and Client Login